# what is latest update installed on sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2.  How can I find out what is the latest updates I have installed on my SQL Server?  Is there some sql command I can enter to findout?

thanks
nick

Comment: Control Panel -> Uninstall a program -> View installed updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your installed SQL instance name and connect to it; then run the below command to know the information about installed version/edition

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), 
SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), 
SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```